# share anonymous mmap between two subprocesses in python

Tags: python, subprocess, mmap

i am trying to make a high speed shared buffer between two different python interpreters, for this i created a file in /tmp then used it to make the mmap object

```
 fd= os.open("file", os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC | os.O_RDWR)
    assert os.write(fd2, bytes('\x00' * Size, encoding='utf-8')) == Size

  mem = mmap.mmap(fd, Size , mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_WRITE)
```

but later i made few tests and i noticed that if i made the mmap anonymous the shared buffer will be much faster, so is there a way to share the anonymous mmap with two python subprocesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory mapped with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` can only ever be shared with descendant processes, and even then not across `execve`. However, you don't need this: the reason for your speedup was just the memory was no longer backed by disk, which is achievable in other ways. The most portable solution is to use [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), which you can use even if you're not using `multiprocessing` to run your processes. Example:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=4096)
shm.buf[0] = 42
print(shm.name)
print('Run the other program with the above name, then press Enter')
input()
print(shm.buf[0])
shm.close()
shm.unlink()
```

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, resource_tracker
name = input("What was the name?")
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name)
resource_tracker.unregister(shm._name, "shared_memory") # work around https://bugs.python.org/issue38119
print(shm.buf[0])
shm.buf[0] += 1
shm.close()
```

You can use `shm.buf` just like you use `mem` in your current code. Note that as an alternative to creating a random name and then sharing it, you can specify a hardcoded name parameter when creating the shared memory, but doing so increases the risk of a name collision.